# How can I stop these buttons overlapping?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I've only know the very basics of HTML and CSS for the last 3 days, so I'm sure that this is a very basic question (which will likely require a simple answer).

I've tried making a website about mathematics as a revision exercise (www.mathematicool.net). On a full width browser, the buttons on the homepage look okay. However, as the browser becomes narrower, and the buttons become spread over multiple rows, they seem to overlap in the vertical direction. In the CSS for this page, I've tried adding `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` to the `.button` class, but this just stretches the buttons, rather than spreading them out. I've also tried using `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`, but neither of these seem to do anything.

What do I need to do?

Comment: So when the browser is resized, how would you like the buttons to react? Would you like them to align vertically on top of eachother? Shrink with the browser to stay on one line (as they are at full width)? Or some other functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additionally, you can use media queries to add CSS specific to the current size of the browser window that the page is in. `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries`

I looked into your website `www.mathematicool.net`. And this should work nicely:

```
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .button {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px;
  }
}
```

Makes it look like:

[image: mathematicool example]

Comment: I do prefer the look of that, but deleting the CSS I had for .button and pasting that in its place did not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't delete your old CSS that you had for .button, you can just add `display: block; margin: 5px` to your existing CSS. The reason why it didn't work is because of the media query. The media query above has it so if your window is less than 700px width, then apply this CSS.

Comment: I understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Margin will not work well on inline elements such as `<a>`. Try setting `display: inline-block` on the links, and then you can set a margin, say `margin: 5px`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `clear: both;` Or if you were floating them you can try `float: none;`